# CSS Width 100% has no effect

Tags: html, css, width

I have some div elements with buttons inside of them. I want the buttons to fill the width of the div, but setting their widths to 100% has no effect.

```css
#header {
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 2.5%;
  width: 42.5%;
}

#header>div {
  display: inline-block;
  display: -moz-inline-box;
  *display: inline;
  /* For IE7 */
  zoom: 1;
  /* Trigger hasLayout */
  width: 33.33%;
}

#previousChapter,
#nextChapter {
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
  color: #1c3e75;
  text-decoration: none;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: "papyrus";
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div><button id="previousChapter" onclick="getPreviousChapter()">Previous</button></div>
  <div>
    <h3 id="chapterTitle">Genesis 1</h3>
  </div>
  <div><button id="nextChapter" onclick="getNextChapter()">Next</button></div>
</div>
```

Here you can see the width of my div:

[image: Div containing the button]

And the width of the button is not filling up the div:

[image: Width not 100%]

Comment: you cannot add a width to inline elements - that's what inline-block is for (also why still coding for ie7?)

Comment: You need to use display:block

Answer (score 1):

use display flex on parent div, set their widths to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the HTML a bit so your header acts as  a navigation bar and set up in a list.

Then i use `display: flex;` to set the buttons side by side and `width: -webkit-fill-available;` to make the div's width fill as much as possible.

Check it out [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/zv2ojfx0/8/)
Read the comments i added if you need help.